# Remove echo command from last run of a do while loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I am learning PHP through codeacademy. I have completed my first do while loop  ([image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdDsJ.png)).

I have a line that does not make logical sense. How do I remove the line:

"The library is still open."

from only the last run of the loop (at 6 o'clock)?

```
<?php
    $closingtime = 6;
    $time = 2;
    do {
        echo "<div class=\"coin\">{$time}</div>";
        echo "The current time is {$time}.";
        echo "<p>The library is still open.</p>";
        $time ++;
  }
  while ($time <= $closingtime);
        echo "<p>The library is closed.</p>";


echo "<p>The library closes at <div class=\"coin\">{$closingtime}</div>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick a little if statement in there to see if they match (if it is not closing time) and voila.

```
<?php

$closingtime = 6;
$time = 2;
do {
    echo "<div class=\"coin\">{$time}</div>";
    echo "The current time is {$time}.";
    if($closingtime != $time)
        echo "<p>The library is still open.</p>";
    $time ++;
}
while ($time <= $closingtime);
echo "<p>The library is closed.</p>";


echo "<p>The library closes at <div class=\"coin\">{$closingtime}</div>";

?>
```

This way, the application will only echo "The library is still open" if $closingtime and $time are *not the same.* Therefore when they are the same, it will not show the statement.